# Can you record video/audio on the iphone, whilst simultaneously playing a separate video (with audio optionally)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, video

Does any `iOS` library `API` support playback and recording of multiple videos simultaneously? For example, does the `AVMutableVideo` composition interface support this?

Can anyone provide a gist of how the code might look?
Does anyone know how performant this is? e.g. is there a way to estimate how many videos at a given quality can play/record simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

AVFoundation library supports the hardware-accelerated playback up to 4 videos simultaneously. The decompression is done at the GPU level so it performs well enough for most cases.
Not sure about the recording part of the question though.